# initializing and passing strings in java

Tags: java, string

I am trying to make a simple coin toss simulation in Java, and after playing around with initializations and such, I can't get the String side initialization to be overridden by the toss simulation.

```
    import java.util.*;

 public class Coin {
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    int randomNum = -1;
    String side = "";
    toss();
    sideUp(randomNum);
    getSideUp(side);
}

public static int toss()
{
    Random rn = new Random();
    int range = 2;
    int randomNum =  rn.nextInt(range);
    return randomNum;
}

public static String sideUp(int randomNum)
{
    String side;
    if (randomNum == 0)
        side = "heads";
    else
        side = "tails";
    return side;
}

public static void getSideUp(String side)
{
    System.out.println("The result is " + side + ".");
}

}
```

Comment: It appears you don't understand variable scoping. I highly suggest starting with a good beginner's book on Java or the Oracle tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

You are throwing away the result of your "toss" method

See what happens if you do

```
int randomNum = toss();
```

Comment: There's more being thrown away.

Answer (score 2):

You return `side` from `sideUp`, but then you don't use that return value. You should assign its return value to your `side` variable in `main`.
You also do the same for `toss` with `randomNum`. Remember that when you pass the variable into a function's parameter, you don't get to see the changes that function made to your variable. (Well, that's a simplification, but mutability is a different concern.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one: Make Random a class member and don't use static methods.

```
package random;

/**
 * Coin
 * @author Michael
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137118/initializing-and-passing-strings-in-java
 * @since 6/16/13 4:00 PM
 */

import java.util.Random;

public class Coin {

    public static final int MAX_VALUE = 2;
    public static final int HEADS_VALUE = 0;
    private final Random random;
    private int numHeads = 0;
    private int numTosses =0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int maxTosses = (args.length > 0 ? Integer.valueOf(args[0]) : 10);
        Coin coin = new Coin();
        for (int i = 0; i < maxTosses; ++i) {
            System.out.println(coin.toss());
        }
        int numHeads = coin.getNumHeads();
        int numTosses = coin.getNumTosses();
        System.out.println(String.format("# heads : %d", numHeads));
        System.out.println(String.format("# tosses: %d", numTosses));
        System.out.println(String.format("%% heads : %10.3f", ((double)numHeads/numTosses)*100.0));
    }

    public Coin() {
        this.random = new Random();
    }

    public Coin(long seed) {
        this.random = new Random(seed);
    }

    public synchronized String toss() {
        int value = this.random.nextInt(MAX_VALUE);
        if (value == HEADS_VALUE) {
            ++numHeads;
        }
        ++numTosses;
        return (value == HEADS_VALUE ? "heads" : "tails");
    }

    public synchronized int getNumHeads() {
        return numHeads;
    }

    public synchronized int getNumTosses() {
        return numTosses;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this -

```
getSideUp(sideUp(toss()));
```

Answer (score 0):

change your main like this

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    int randomNum=toss();
   String side= sideUp(randomNum);
    getSideUp(side);
}
```